# Check if the link results in reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I develope a chrome extension; with a content script I inject some code in the page. What I want is an event that triggers if the current tab is going to update.
I tried to catch the click event of an `a`-element and it does work in somehow 80% of all cases. I already check if it's an anchor, but there are still many links which don't reload the page or forward to another.

```
$('a', document).click(function (e) {
// ...
});
```

So, what I want is described in the following three steps:

1. Event: the page is going to reload
2. prevent it from reloading, execute some code
3. trigger reloading the page afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, have you considered listening to [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event? It's fired when the page is about to unload (also including refresh the current page).